# Need help adding the difference between times. 12:00 PM not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

So I want to find the difference between the hours and add them all up. But when I have use 12:00 PM (or am) as the time it returns 0. If I use 12:01 PM as in **example 2** it works. If I have 12:00 PM only twice in the formula as in **example 3** it works. I need **example 1** to work, it should be returning "24" in J4. Any fixes? I need it to still be in the Time format.

Each Example has the exact same formula at work, just different numbers for D4,D7, and D10

[image: The problem]

Comment: Change your format to `[h]:mm`  8+8+8 = 24 which is a full day and the datetime on a full day is `1.0` which when formatted for just time will show `0`.

Comment: @ScottCraner you should put yours as the answer, it solves the request: `=TEXT((E4-D4)+(G4-F4)+(I4-H4),"[h]:mm")`. Another idea I had is my complicated  `=HOUR(E12-D12)&":"&MINUTE(E12-D12)`